# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #2](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/election/2) on Cardano has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: eddex]

[image: Matthias Sieber]

[image: Marek Mahut - StakeNuts]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking gRebel for their term as a moderator on Cardano, which has come to a close with this election:

[image: gRebel]

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/election/2) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4873359379660800).

Comment: Thanks to everyone who voted for me, I hope I can help to further grow this community as part of the mod team! :)